# Find out local IP address of the backend in a local network frontend. Dynamic in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dns, ip, frontend, backend

I have got a docker backend and frontend running in a local network on a raspberry pi. If I now access the frontend from another device in the network via the raspberry pis ip address and the correct port, the frontend works, but my frontend does not have the correct IP address of the backend. The IP may change if the pi is connedcted to another network, so static ips do not work. If localhost is used as IP it just works if the frontend is openend on the pi, but if it is opened on another device localhost would be wrong.

So my Question now is, how can I find out the IP address of the backend in my frontend with java script code. I need to get the backend IP purely through browser side java script.

I already tried to use dns package for node, but thats just for external IP addresses which I do not want to have or find out. I just want to find out the local address because my system should only be accessible locally.

**EDIT:**

Idea: I can get the URL of my frontend in JS code (window.location.href), but htat may no be an IP address if a hostname is set and it may opr may not contain the port in addition to the ip/hostname. So I also cannot get the ip address in every case.

**EDIT 2:**
For now I solved this with just getting the URL via window.location.href an cutting out the ip/hostname before the '**:**'. But this just works if you are sticking to a Port which needs to be specified and put in the URL. But it works as a workaround until I find a better solution.

Comment: `The IP may change if the pi is connedcted to another network` ...... `I just want to find out the local address because my system should only be accessible locally.` ...if the Pi isn't on the same LAN as the "front end" then you cannot access it locally.

Comment: Yes that is correct, but back- and frontend are always running on the pi. So they are always in the same network (back- and frontend), but the backend does not have the same ip address if they both(back- and frontend) move to another network.

Comment: if the devices are on different ip it not goine to work or you have to use static ip address for backend device

Comment: what do you mean the back end and front end are both running on the pi. the question is making less and less sense.

Comment: Im sorry XD I really try to explain it clearly:
Backend --> Docker NodeJS/Express running on PI
Frontend --> Docker ReactJS running on PI

Access: From another device (e.g. laptop) <pi-ip>:<frontend)port>

Backend access: <pi-ip>:<backend_port>

Now I need to find out in the frontend JS code the pi-ip on my laptop

Comment: is there are two pi you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can use if/else conditions in a for loop to check which IP address gives you the response you needed:

```
for(var n=1; n<24) { // connect to 192.168.0.n 
    if (/* gives you replay */) {
        return;
    } else {
        // continue the loop
    }
}
```

If the IP and port gives you the response then you connect to that.

Comment: it might work. or you might end up connecting to your smart fridge.

Comment: That is a nice idea, but how can I be sure that the local address is always of the form: 192.168.0.n. It may be 192.168.x.n, or even something like: 10.x.x.x?

Comment: it is the logic i want to explain

Comment: isn't the last octet for the router is generally 01? just scan the third octet to find the router then you scan the scan the rest of the network.. that should work under 99% of cases.